# Button loading state and ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

ng-disabled not working with `$().button('loading') & .button('reset')`. How to fix this issue?
Also I have [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/etHsax8bFOtpEQyk0wnN?p=preview).

Comment: @OrGuz, as you can see in plunker, I want to make button loading while http request. And if it is success, button should be disabled. But also it should be enabled back on timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind button text to the scope and modify it according to the relevant state.

HTML:

```
<button id="someButton" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"  
ng-disabled="!someArray.someBool" ng-click="someClick()">{{button}}</button>
```

Before click - Button
While loading - Loading...
After loading - Loaded

I used a $timeout function of 2 seconds instead of making a real async request.
Controller:

```
$scope.someClick = function() {
    $scope.button="loading...";
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.someArray.someBool = false;
          $scope.button="loaded";
        }, 2000);
  }
```

[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QfuCUJt2d2lyvlXFTfCc?p=preview)